# How can i bind jquery select2 to new added selects?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i have a razor-mvc web and a couple of select's on a form. I bind this selects with the select2 plugin in jquery like this:

```
$('select.company_select, select.positions_select').select2();
```

And my form is an ajax form (ajax by javascript, not by Ajax.BeginForm).
The thing is that when i submit the form, i add another form with the submited values of the first form, but the select's on that new form wont apply the select2 plugin. I know that this is normal because the new item and should be binded with .on() or .live() but i dont know how to do it.

Can you help me with it?

Comment: You cannot use delegation with plugin, you have to initialize your select2 elements inside the ajax callback function

Comment: Does this apply to the select2 plugin or pretty much any jQuery plugin? The comment by @A.Wolff above is 5 years old - does it still apply in 2018?

Comment: @HPWD some plugins handle delegation but most don't. This  is the responsability of plugin's developper to handle it or not by design. Generally plugins that handle it have a **seletor** parameter that can be passed during initialisation.

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you for the clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

use [ajaxcomplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){
  $(".select2").select2();
});
```

Comment: Nice solution, but only accessable for selectboxes that comes through an ajax request. But not for selectboxes dynamically created without ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing ajax call so make sure you re-init the select on whatever other selects you want in complete for any new select boxes on the page..

so your ajax call will look something like

```
$.ajax({ 
     url: '.../', 
     data..., 
     type...,
     success: function(data) 
     {
         $('#newFormAddedID select').select2();
     }
```

Should do the trick.. 
you can also do it in complete:function(... if the form gets added regardless of wether the ajax call is successful or not.

Comment: This worked for me. If possible though, I'd rather delegate this out but a comment above indicates that plugins have to be reinit'd but was also posted in 2013. Here's hoping! :D